# How do i convert the result of the input into an int in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm learning f# and doing a function which asks for the user to input a number. The function will then display the users input and if it's a positive or negative number. However, when I try running the program it errors and states that the input is a string instead of an int. I don't know a way to convert the function output into a string.

```
    open System

let sign num  =
   if num > 0 then "positive"
   elif num < 0 then "negative"
   else "zero"

let main() =
   Console.Write("please enter a number:")
   let input = Console.ReadLine()
   Console.Write("The number {0}", sign 1)
   System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore


main()
```

Comment: @Gustavo the duplicate isn't the best choice - it doesn't offer the obvious choice `(int)` and goes directly to Parse, not even TryParse

Comment: BTW make sure you either `open System` or use `System.Int32.TryParse`. `Int32.TryParse` exists since .NET 1.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can remove the duplicate, but the difference you mention refers to the answer, not the question. There have been many questions like that. I acknowledge your answer is more complete.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos btw why do you write ``(int)input`` instead of ``int input`` that's a bit misleading I think, because it resemble more the C# cast than the F# generic ``int`` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use <s>`(int)input`</s> `int input`. Under the covers this parses the input and returns an int or throws a System.FormatException.

Another option is to use Int32's TryParse method and return the both the result and success indicator as a tuple. You can also deconstruct the tuple in the same line :

```
let (ok,number)= System.Int32.TryParse input
let message=if ok then 
                sprintf "The number %i" number 
            else
                sprintf "%s is not a number" input
Console.WriteLine message
```

Comment: As Gustavo notes, `(int)input` looks misleadingly like a cast - you should use `int input` instead, which makes it obvious that `int` is just a function being applied.